# Traefik Route Prefix

Tags: kubernetes, traefik

I've configured an Ingress with config:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nuclio-dashboard
  namespace: nuclio
spec:
  rules:
    - host: nuc.local
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /nuclio
            backend:
              serviceName: nuclio-dashboard
              servicePort: 8070
```

Not when I go to `nuc.local/nuclio` I'm getting a response but the page requests js and css files at:

```
http://nuc.local/assets/css/vendor-fc43143698.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

I want every request mage from `/nuclio` to `/` to go to `/nuclio`.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using Traefik v2, you need something like a [redirectRegex Middleware](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/middlewares/redirectregex/), for traefik to do this. I think it would go like this.

```
---
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: Middleware
metadata:
  name: test-redirectregex
  namespace: nuclio
spec:
  redirectRegex:
    regex: ^http://nuc.local/?$$
    replacement: http://nuc.local/nuclio/
    permanent: true
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.middlewares: nuclio-test-redirectregex@kubernetescrd
  name: nuclio-dashboard
  namespace: nuclio
spec:
  rules:
    - host: nuc.local
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: nuclio-dashboard
              servicePort: 8070
```

Another take on it could be to use the [replacePath Middleware](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/middlewares/replacepath/), which would then look like this:

```
---
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: Middleware
metadata:
  name: test-replacepath
  namespace: nuclio
spec:
  replacePath:
    path: /nclio
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.middlewares: nuclio-test-replacepath@kubernetescrd
  name: nuclio-dashboard
  namespace: nuclio
spec:
  rules:
    - host: nuc.local
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: nuclio-dashboard
              servicePort: 8070
```

Let us know how that goes.